# MSSQL database LDAP/Windows Authentication from Unix server using Java JDBC connection

Tags: java, sql-server, unix, ldap

I have a java application running from Unix server and connecting to MSSQL database using Java JDBC SQL authentication method. I am trying to create JDBC connection using LDAP/Windows authentication method instead of SQL Server authentication.

I googled a lot and tried several answers from StackOverflow to use `jtds` and `jdbc` driver but none of these are working in my case. I there any way to create Java JDBC connection using database LDAP authentication from Unix server?